# Composer Fatal error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv() in phar

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm using WHM/Cpanel with PHP 7.0 with all extensions like iconv, mbstring installed via easyapache 4. But when i am trying to install a magento plugin by caling
    composer require firebear/importexportfree

I am getting this message on putty,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv() in 
phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/polyfill-
mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 513
```

I had checked on the server for the status of both the extensions iconv and mbstring using php --ri iconv and php --ri mbstring

Answer (score 1):

Symfony have iconv-polyfill which you need to add in your composer

```
composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv
```

Comment: I had updated my PHP 7.0.X and issue resolved., Bu i tried the above code but no use at all. :